# Durandal - Open multiple tabs with same view and view model

Tags: knockout.js, durandal, hottowel

We have a main menu item, say WorkFlow. Whenever you click on it, it opens a tab under which the UI for the workflow is loaded. Please note that this tab is not the browser tab, but a tab inside application UI. The workflow has four screens that are driven by their own views and viewmodels. A user can execute this workflow by filling in data, making selections, etc. and moving back and forth between the workflow screens.

The requirement is that when user repeatedly click on the WorkFlow menu item, multiple tabs should be opened up, each housing the workflow screens that can be executed independently of the same workflows opened in other tabs. For example, in first tab, you could move to screen 2 in the workflow, while in the second tab you could move to fourth screen and then if you switch between these tabs, each workflow maintains it's state and data, like kayak.com works. The crux of the problem is that we don't really want the view models to be shared between the multiple instances of the same view that we are opening in the tabs. How can this be achieved using Durandal/KnockOut?

Thank you,

Subin

Answer (score 0):

So in essence you're trying to display multiple instances of the same Viewmodel next to each other right?
How bout changing so that Durandal displays only the BASE-Workflow ViewModel, but that one internally renders X times using Templates?

To catch the click on the TabItem, instead of creating a MapNav use MapRouter, and set visibility to false, then in the Shell, or wherever you're displaying the Item create your custom entry with a Click data-bind. In there you could send some specific code to your BaseWorkmodel so it understands to create one more template.

I'm pretty new to Durandal too but thats how I'd try getting around the issue

Hope this helps